# AsyncFileUpload to update some text box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp-classic

I have Ajax AsyncFileUpload on my site, 
here is what i need to do:
1. when the user browse and choose a file to upload, I need to update another asp .net texbox with some value - this value is using the complete browsed path adding some string.

as this string to update is quit complicated  and uses the all path of the file i want to do it on Asp .net C# code.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, the file path is not exposed to javascript, it's a security feature.
The file has to be uploaded before you know the path, and even then you will not know the full local path.

If your application feature  is centered around modifying the path name i suppose it could make sense to have them enter the file name in a seperate textbox, then you could submit the text trough ajax to make the modifications, but that really depends on what you want.

Comment: Lets I am able to get the complete file path on server side using postedFile.fileName, but i am unable to then updtae the TextBox with the String i want, how can i accomlish it?

Comment: are you using the AsyncFileUpload from the AJAX control toolkit ? The OnClientUploadComplete event should work for you, you could store the full path name in a session variable on the server and then retrieve it using a pagemethod from that event, see http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx for more

Comment: Agree with @helmus, at least for modern browsers. ( I guess IE6 used to send the full path to the server. )

helmus, a typo in your first sentence : the file PATH is not exposed to javascrit, but the file NAME is.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location ="yourpath?string="+string
```

After you passing this string next page you need to do something like this to get that full path.

```
$(function()
{
    $.extend({
        getUrlVars: function(){
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
            {
              hash = hashes[i].split('=');
              vars.push(hash[0]);
              vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
           return vars;
        },
       getUrlVar: function(name){
          return $.getUrlVars()[name];
        }
    });
    var previous_email = $.getUrlVar('string');
    $("#pemail").val(''+previous_email+'')
});
```

This is retrieve your path what you send in previous page. The cons is I used here get method.